# Want to use any method in sql server 2005 convert rows data in table column

Tags: sql-server-2005, switch-statement, pivot

Data are given in below Pic

[image: Table Data]

Now I want to rearrange the data in the following format:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to use PIVOT? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx?

Comment: Also, aside from @Cristian_I comment that SQL Server supports a `PIVOT` function, for future questions be sure to post your sample data and expected output as text, not images. Bonus points if you post it with a DDL.